# Is there a way to force an instance group to "work harder" at one task?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, multiple-instances

I set up an instance group on the Google Cloud Platform to run a single python script. After running the script for a few hours, it looks like only one instance (4 vCPUs, 16 GB memory) has been running consistently at around 25% CPU, while the other two instances have been at 2%.

Is there a way to tell each instance to contribute more resources to run the script faster? Note that I am not even close to the designated 60% CPU utilization before the load is shared, among other instances.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly with Google Cloud.

You will need to design/redesign your software to support multiple CPUs in a cluster. Not a simple task unless designed that way.